# How to zoom out a material in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, camera

Ok, new to skyboxes here but Im having a problem involving a radial gradient material I'm using as a skybox and the field of view on my camera. My problem is this: the gradient looks great and ou can see the gradient part only when the camera's field of view is really high.

I built my whole scene at field of view 7 and at that proximity, I don't get a gradient here is the comparison:

[image]
[image]

I have my whole scene (the objects) in an empty, but even if I up their z value at the high field of view they don't look like they used to. Without completely rebuilding EVERYTHING in my scene position wise, how can I zoom out my material as the skybox?

Is there a way to up the field of view without moving away from the objects in my scene?

I can post my shader code as well.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to up the field of view without moving away from the objects in my scene?

Here's the key: Because FOV basically zooms in you'll get all the ugly artefacts associated with being eye-ball close with something, such as your skybox. So, unfortunately the answer is no, you need to position your camera further away and increase the scale of your objects. To compensate just scale up all the objects in your scene, preferably in your 3D modelling app rather than in Unity.